# SonarQube 6.7 - Change login id for users

Tags: sonarqube

We are migrating our SQ 6.7 instance to another domain, in this domain the users have another username to work with. How can we ensure the user accounts in the database are matched to the new login ids ?

f.e, can we change the ID's in the database ? i see there is a common users table. 
I checked the Web-API, but could not find a method that can do what we want.

Tried adding the new username as SCM account prior to taking a backup and did a test migration, when i logged on to the new instance i still had a 2nd new user account in sonarqube, my new login id is the same as the SCM Account added to the other account, that is clearly visible in the UI (casing is also the same)

We are currently on LDAP authentication and are moving to HTTP Headers, but both should be able to use these accounts if im right. We are not able to change the headers such that they match the old login id.

Hope you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is not possible. See https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/FR-42 for details.